# For loop not working within a function

Tags: r

As a newbie to R I am confused with the following. Trying to work a method of imputting NAs in a dataframe with the values of another, related dataframe, I try to resort to this function:

```
prueba = function(x)
{
     for (w in 1:nrow(x))
     {
         datanona[w, 1] = ifelse(is.na(x[w, 1]), stepsintervals[which(stepsintervals[ ,1] == x[w, 3]),
                                  2], x[w, 1])
     }
}
```

When I run `prueba(data)`, and then `head(data)`, the NAs are still there. Now, if I just use the loop within the function (with data instead of x), the NAs in data disappear and are replaced by the intended values from stepsintervals.

There is probably a simple explanation for this discrepancy, but I haven't been able to find it. Is there a kind soul who can throw some light into this issue?

Comment: Could you provide some example of data?

Comment: It would be better if you could provide a representative example of each dataframe you mention so your code is reproducible.  As a first thought, you likely want to have your second dataframe as a parameter instead of assuming it is globally accessible.

Comment: You won't get any result from your function unless you return something.

Answer (score 1):

When you call `prueba(.)`, it will execute the `for` loop but then at the end of the function, there is no return and hence it gives the impression of nothing happening.

Presumably, you want to have the results captured in `datanona`, in which case, you need to tell the function to return the object

```
prueba = function(x)
{
     for (w in 1:nrow(x))
     {
         datanona[w, 1] = ifelse(is.na(x[w, 1]), stepsintervals[which(stepsintervals[ ,1] == x[w, 3]),
                                  2], x[w, 1])
     }

     ### ADD A RETURN LINE
     return(datanona)
}
```

Comment: Its often better to have a brief explanation than to have code only answers.

Comment: @MadScienceDreams, you are correct.   The explanation appears as a comment in the code.  I'll edit the answer to be more explicit

Answer (score 0):

You say you are running:

```
prueba(data)
head(data)
```

But you should be running:

```
newData <- prueba(data)
head(newData)
```

You also should return(datanona) as the last line of your function. Your provided code seems to be examining the head of your old unaltered dataset.

Answer (score 0):

You may find a faster result and perhaps easier to follow by doing something like this pseudocode.  In R it is usually not necessary to write loops for subsetting and replacement.

Assume `x` is your data frame.

```
# the id column is column 1 of stepsintervals and column 3 of df
datanona <- merge(x, stepsintervals, by="id", all.x=TRUE)

#assuming column 3 of stepsintervals was named imputed
#assuming column 1 of df is called value
datanona[is.na(datanona$value),"value"] <- datanona[is.na(datanona$value), "imputed"]
```

You can then drop any unneeded columns in `datanona` like so: `datanona$imputed <- NULL`

Hope this helps.